# Nested loops with using Streams to achieve best performance

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I started learning Java 8 features, streams and lambdas in particular, and I'm quite confused.
I tried to rewrite the piece of code below

```
MyClass graph = new MyClass(V);

for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < numOfVertices; j++) {
      if (adjMatrix[i][j] != 0) {
         graph.addEdge(i, j, adjMatrix[i][j]);
      }
   }
}
```

I wrote this:

```
int b = IntStream.range(0, numOfVertices - 1).parallel()
   .map(i -> (IntStream.range(0, numOfVertices - 1))
      .map(j -> {
         if (adjMatrix[i][j] != 0) {
            graph.addEdge(i, j, adjMatrix[i][j]);
         }
      }));
```

Of course it doesn't work. What would be the proper way to rewrite the code above? I'm also looking for the best performance, so I attempted to use the parallel method.

Thanks!

Comment: "Of course it doesn't work" - give more details. Is there an error, or is the result incorrect, or something else?

Comment: _best_ would be something you would have to measure; in 99% of the cases stick to the plain old loops you have.

Comment: Note that parallelising this only makes sense if your `graph` object can allow parallel updates without using a lock. I suspect this is not the case unless your graph data structure is quite carefully designed with this requirement in mind.

Comment: First, why did you change `numOfVertices` to `numOfVertices - 1` when turning to stream? Second, is `graph.addEdge(…)` thread safe? Did you test without `.parallel()`?

Comment: It's my mistake, it should be just numOfVertices.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the parallel updates thing. I think I'm going to modify the data structure so I can work with parallel streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

If you want "best performance", the shorter time in iteration: Use "for loop" for small matrix, for bigger cases you can consider use "parallel streams"

## .. long answer

I created a test to measure the average time of execution one of three options.

"For loop:"

```java
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
    }
}
```

"IntStream.range:"

```java
IntStream.range(0, size)
        .forEach(i -> (IntStream.range(0, size))
                .forEach(j -> {
                    doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
                }));
```

"IntStream.range parallel:"

```java
IntStream.range(0, size).parallel()
        .forEach(i -> (IntStream.range(0, size))
                .forEach(j -> {
                    doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
                }));
```

This section was removed as I could not simpulate it's time cost:

```java
      if (adjMatrix[i][j] != 0) {
         graph.addEdge(i, j, adjMatrix[i][j]);
      }
```

Below is the whole test code that perform measurement for different matrix.
It runs every case 10000 times and gives the average time. 
Here are the results for run on my computer. For small matrix (form 1 x 1 to 100 x 100) for loop is the best option. When matrix is big (more than 500 x 500) using "IntStream.range parallel" is faster. "IntStream.range" is always worse than "For loop" for every case.

```
Size: 1
IntStream.range parallel: 0.002300
         IntStream.range: 0.002200
                For loop: 0.000000
Size: 5
IntStream.range parallel: 0.023000
         IntStream.range: 0.000500
                For loop: 0.000000
Size: 10
IntStream.range parallel: 0.025800
         IntStream.range: 0.000300
                For loop: 0.000100
Size: 50
IntStream.range parallel: 0.042200
         IntStream.range: 0.004300
                For loop: 0.000900
Size: 100
IntStream.range parallel: 0.035000
         IntStream.range: 0.006000
                For loop: 0.004300
Size: 500
IntStream.range parallel: 0.060200
         IntStream.range: 0.102000
                For loop: 0.079600
Size: 1000
IntStream.range parallel: 0.122000
         IntStream.range: 0.379800
                For loop: 0.347400
```

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Arrays.asList(1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000).forEach(
                size -> {
                    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
                    Integer[][] numOfVertices = createArray(size);

                    Map<String, Runnable> toRun = Map.of(
                            "For loop:",
                            () -> {
                                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                                        doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "IntStream.range:",
                            () -> {
                                IntStream.range(0, size)
                                        .forEach(i -> (IntStream.range(0, size))
                                                .forEach(j -> {
                                                    doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
                                                }));
                            },
                            "IntStream.range parallel:",
                            () -> {
                                IntStream.range(0, size).parallel()
                                        .forEach(i -> (IntStream.range(0, size))
                                                .forEach(j -> {
                                                    doSomething(numOfVertices[i][j]);
                                                }));
                            }
                    );

                    int howManyTimes = 10000;
                    Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
                    toRun.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
                        double time = (((double)IntStream.range(0, howManyTimes).mapToObj(
                                (x) -> executionTime(e.getValue()))
                                .reduce(Long::sum).get()) / howManyTimes);

                        map.put(e.getKey(), time);
                    });

                    map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
                        System.out.println(String.format("%25s %f", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
                    });
                }
        );
    }

    private static Integer[][] createArray(int size) {
        Integer[][] val = new Integer[size][size];
        IntStream.range(0, size).forEach(
                i -> IntStream.range(0,size).forEach(
                        j -> val[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 100)
                )
        );
        return  val;
    }

    private static int doSomething(int val) {
        return val * val;
    }

    private static long executionTime(Runnable execThis)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        execThis.run();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (endTime-startTime);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for such a great explanation with examples!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless to performance this is a simple form rewriting it with stream:

```
                IntStream.range(0, numOfVertices - 1)
                 .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, numOfVertices - 1)
                   .filter(j -> adjMatrix[i][j] != 0)
                     .forEach(j -> graph.addEdge(i, j, adjMatrix[i][j])));
```

Comment: Yep, I agree, I've completely ignored the inside loops logic

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works as intended, however, as you mentioned, the performance is not that great